# Python: how to create a graph with networkx with correspondence with another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I have two dataframe `df` and `df1`. `df` contains the information of some nodes. So

```
df  Name       Age
0   Jack       33
1   Anna       25
2   Emilie     49
3   Frank      19
4   John       42
```

while `df1` contains the info of the number of contacts between two people. In `df1` we can have some people that don't appear in `df`

```
df1    Name1    Name2   c
0      Frank    Paul    2
1      Julia    Anna    5
2      Frank    John    1
3      Emilie   Jack    3
4      Tom      Steven  2
5      Tom      Jack    5
```

I would like to create an adjaceny matrix with the nodes in `df` and the information between the connections in `df1`.

In order to create the adjacency matrix from `df1`, I did the following:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from.pandas_dataframe(df1, 'Name1', 'Name2', ['c'])
adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

However, in this way there is not a direct corespondency with `df`. In fact I would like to generate a `6x6` adjacency matrix where, the `row 0` and the `column 0` correspond to `Jack`. The `row 1` and the `column 1` correspond to `Anna` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The adjacency matrix returned by NetworkX is sparse. First, convert it to a dense matrix:

```
dense = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
```

Create a dataframe whose content is the adjacency matrix and rows and columns represent all nodes:

```
adj_df = pd.DataFrame(dense, index=G.nodes(), columns=G.nodes())
```

Finally, take the subset of the dataframe, as defined by `df`:

```
adj_df.loc[df.Name, df.Name]
#        Jack  Anna  Emilie  Frank  John
#Jack       0     0       1      0     0
#Anna       0     0       0      0     0
#Emilie     1     0       0      0     0
#Frank      0     0       0      0     1
#John       0     0       0      1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a digraph by adding nodes and edges manually:

```
def from_pandas_dataframe(df, col_from, col_to, col_weight=None, nodes=None):
    """Construct a digraph from dataframe.

    :param df: dataframe contains edge/relation information
    :param col_from: dataframe column name for start of edge
    :param col_to: dataframe column name for end of edge
    :param col_weight: dataframe column name for col_weight, defaults 1 if not provided
    :param nodes: nodes for the graph, default to use nodes from df if not provided
    :return:
    """
    g = nx.OrderedDiGraph()

    # add nodes
    if not nodes:
        nodes = set(df[col_from]) | set(df[col_to])
    g.add_nodes_from(nodes)

    # add edges
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        from_node, to_node = row[col_from], row[col_to]
        if from_node in nodes and to_node in nodes:
            weight = 1 if not col_weight else row[col_weight]
            g.add_edge(from_node, to_node, weight=weight)

    return g
```

Param `nodes` specify the nodes in graph and edge with node not in it will be omitted:

```
g = from_pandas_dataframe(df1, 'Name1', 'Name2', col_weight='c', nodes=df['Name'].tolist())
adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(g)
```

Running on the sample data:

```
>>> print(g.nodes)
['Jack', 'Anna', 'Emilie', 'Frank', 'John']
>>> print(adj)
  (2, 0)    3
  (3, 4)    1
```